# Interpretation of proportion coefficient

Tags: regression, interpretation, proportion, log-linear

I know that I should be able to work this out but I am struggling. My dependent variable is a log variable (call it y) and my independent variable is a proportion that takes a value between 0 and 1 (call it x).

I am struggling to interpret what Beta on the independent variable means for the log y variable.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What about the interpretation makes it different from any other regression?